# Add total price to react shopping cart

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and followed this tutorial to built a shopping cart. The code is pretty simple and straight forward but I would like for it to display the total price of products. How would I implement that within this code?

Here's the code. I've later separated these into 3 files, "Products", "Cart" and "Productspage" but displayed it here all together so it would simpler to see it.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import './ProductsPage.css'

const PAGE_PRODUCTS = 'products';
const PAGE_CART = 'cart';

function ProductsPage() {

    const [cart, setCart] = useState ([]);

    const [page, setPage] = useState (PAGE_PRODUCTS);

    const [products] = useState ([
        {
            name: 'Breakfast box ',
            cost:'9.99$',
            image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578863950596-a74dfe8267b5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1573&q=80',

        },
        {
            name: 'Breakfast box ',
            cost:'8.99$',
            image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557686652-6731ba12410f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80',

        },
    ])

    const addToCart = (product) => {
        setCart ([...cart, {...product}])
    }

    const removeFromCart = (productToRemove) => {
        setCart(cart.filter(product => product !== productToRemove))
    }

    const navigateTo = (nextPage) => {
        setPage(nextPage);
    };

    const renderProducts = () => (
        <>
         <h1>Products</h1>
            <div className="products">
            {products.map((product , index) => (
            <div className="product" key={index}>
               <h3>{product.name}</h3>
               <h4>{product.cost}</h4>
               <img src={product.image} alt={product.name}/>
               <button onClick={() => addToCart(product)}>
                   Add to Cart
                </button>
            </div>
                
                ))}
         </div>
         </>
    );

        const renderCart = () => (
            <>
            <h1>Cart</h1>
               <div className="products">
               {cart.map((product , index) => (
               <div className="product" key={index}>
                  <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                  <h4>{product.cost}</h4>
                  <img src={product.image} alt={product.name}/>
                  <button onClick={() => removeFromCart(product)}>
                      Remove
                   </button>
               </div>
                   
                   ))}
            </div>
            </>
        )

    return (
            <div className="productspage">
            <header>
                <button onClick={()=> navigateTo(PAGE_CART)}>
                    Go to Cart ({cart.length})
                </button>
                <button onClick={()=> navigateTo(PAGE_PRODUCTS)}>
                    View Products
                </button>
            </header>
            {page === PAGE_PRODUCTS && renderProducts()}
            {page === PAGE_CART && renderCart()}
            </div>
    );
};

export default ProductsPage;
```

Answer (score 1):

you could simply loop through array created from object, and then convert string cost to numeric (by replacing $ to nothing and cast cart to numeric with + before that) and then sum up all of them like here:

```
Object.keys(cart).reduce(
    (prevVal, currentVal) =>
      prevVal + +cart[currentVal].cost.replace("$", ""),
    0
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this function with your products list wherever you want the total cost to appear.

```
const getTotalCost = (productList) => {
  return productList.reduce((totalCost, { cost: itemCost }) => totalCost + parseFloat(itemCost), 0);
};
```

This is just a regular JavaScript function that iterates the list of products and sums the `cost` key and returns it.

It's not accessing any props or state so can sit outside of your component body.

Comment: Updated the above to use `parseFloat` rather than `parseInt`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I've placed the function before the ProductsPage function and called it at the bottom after rendering the cart but I'm having a bunch of errors back. Any idea why is this happening?

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'reduce' of undefined" not sure if that helps

Comment: Are you passing the list of products into the `getTotalCost` function? `getTotalList(products)`. With `products` coming from `const [products] = useState ([{}])`.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. How do I set  ProductList equal to the list of products?

Comment: `productList` is just a named argument of the `getTotalCost` function which can be set by passing your `products` list to it from inside your React component. So depending on where you want to you want to use/display your total cost, just pass your `products` variable to it `getTotalCost(products)`. The `getTotalCost` function will take your products list (`products`) and return a sum of the total cost of your products.

Comment: I think I get it now but I still get "productList.reduce is not a function" when clicking on Cart.

Comment: Please add a Codesandbox example of what you have so far and the community can help some more.

Answer (score 0):

Check it out i have added js code with comments to understand easily:

```js
`const [total,setTotal]=useState(0)` //make a new state variable
const cart =[
        {
            name: 'Breakfast box ',
            cost:'9.99$',
            image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578863950596-a74dfe8267b5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1573&q=80',

        },
        {
            name: 'Breakfast box ',
            cost:'8.99$',
            image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557686652-6731ba12410f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80',

        },
    ]

//modified addToCart
const addToCart = (product) => {
  const products = [...cart, product]
  console.log(products)
 
  const totalPrice = products.reduce((acc, curr)=>{ //calculate total
    let cur =curr.cost.match(/\d./g).join('') //parse string to integer(cost)
      return acc + Number(cur); 
    }, 0)
  console.log("total:", totalPrice);

  // setCart (products);
  //setTotal(totalPrice);
}
//end addToCart


const newProduct = {
            name: 'Breakfast box ',
            cost:'7.99$',
            image: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1557686652-6731ba12410fixlib=rb1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=63',

        }
addToCart(newProduct)
```